# Internet speed very slow in Linux but not in Windows

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

On Windows, downloading a 500 MB file takes less than a minute, but on Linux it is taking nearly half an hour.

Why is my internet speed so much slower on Linux than on Windows, and what can I do to speed it up?

I'm using a wireless network adapter made by Panda Wireless that's working perfectly fine on Windows, so I suspect it's due to a driver issue or something.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0673 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5598 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lsmod | grep rtl` :

```
rt2800usb              24576  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              81920  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              49152  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              552960  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              450560  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
```

Output of `iwconfig` :

```
wlx9cefd5fe85d8  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Alderhouse"  
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:AB:F0:1E:77:40   
Bit Rate=115.6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Encryption key:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:976  Invalid misc:14   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: check which wireless protocol (a, b, g, n, ...) that the connection is making under Windows and Linux. On linux `iwconfig` would be useful.

Comment: I posted the output of iwconfig above.  It appears to be using the n protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RT5372 driver is slow and there is currently no software fix for this.

https://www.google.com/search?q=ralink+RT5372+slow

The recommended solution seems be that you should use a different WiFi dongle. Unfortunately.